# What happens when using a non-whole number as an index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, syntax

Given a non whole number, or floating-point number (e.g. `3.5`), what happens when using that number as an index?

When using a floating-point number to access an index of an array or string, `undefined` is returned.

```js
'hello'[3.5]; // => undefined
```

When using floating-point numbers as indices passed to `Array.prototype.slice()` or `String.prototype.slice()` it seems the number is rounded down or the decimal is ignored.

```js
['a','b','c','d','e'].slice(3.5, 4.5); // => ['d']
'hello'.slice(0.5, 1.5); // => 'h'
```

Why the different behavior, and what is actually happening here?

Comment: For array access `3.5` is converted to a string and then treated as property access. Property access works with arrays and strings because they are also objects. You can try this: `x = 'hello'; x.y = 'world'; x[3.5] = 'goodbye'; console.log(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.slice` internally [rounds its arguments to integers](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-string.prototype.slice).

> String.prototype.slice ( **start, end** )
>
> 1. Let O be ? RequireObjectCoercible(this value).
> 2. Let S be ? ToString(O).
> 3. Let len be the length of S.
> 4. Let intStart be ? **ToIntegerOrInfinity(start).**
> 5. If intStart is -∞, let from be 0.
> 6. Else if intStart < 0, let from be max(len + intStart, 0).
> 7. Else, let from be min(intStart, len).
> 8. If end is undefined, let intEnd be len; else let intEnd be ? **ToIntegerOrInfinity(end).**
> 9. ...

where `ToIntegerOrInfinity` [does](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-tointegerorinfinity)

> 5. Let integer be floor(abs(ℝ(number))).

In contrast, when you do

```
'hello'[3.5];
```

no such rounding occurs.